# Project android fails to run over Page Indicator and CirclePageIndicator

Tags: android, dependencies

I am writing a code for Android studio and I need Page Indicator and viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator but these are telling me errors so I cannot compile my code.
I need for every Fragment to have indicicators in the bottom
If you have an simple way to do that just let me know because I have 2 days searched how to make for each page with indicators
I have tried this from github but doesn't work.

https://github.com/vivchar/ViewPagerIndicator

This is my code in build gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.zhuniqia.searchfinal"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}



buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

this is the main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF000000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/pagerIndicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:padding="3dp"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

This is the Java

```
public PageIndicator indicator;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle

Step 1. Add the JitPack repository to your build file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Step 2. Add the dependency

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.vivchar:ViewPagerIndicator:${LATEST_VERSION}'
}
```

I don't see these dependecies in your build.gradle file.Also,read again and follow the steps from the README file from the link you've shared.

Comment: I am facing with problem 
Could not get unknown property 'LATEST_VERSION' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts

Comment: Change LATEST_VERSION with 1.1.0. I mean , dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.vivchar:ViewPagerIndicator:1.1.0'
}

Comment: I have this fixed but do you have any idea to change the color of the ViewPagerIndicator ?

Comment: Try with : app:itemSelectedTint = "#color" and app:itemTint = "#anothercolor"

Comment: It is not working because this CirclePageIndicator has none app:itemSelectedTint

Comment: Your layout should contain this view  : <com.github.vivchar.viewpagerindicator.ViewPagerIndicator
        android:id = "@+id/view_pager_indicator"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        app:itemSelectedTint = "@color/colorAccent"
        app:itemSize = "16dp"
        app:itemTint = "@color/colorPrimary"
        />